# Iterating through a tuple list and somehow the 'a' is always treated as even number in the tuple (a,b)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am able to get the code work good when the compound statement is changed to 
if `a % 2 == 0` and `b % 2 == 0`:
But as I am in learning phase could someone please guide me in explaining the error in the original code.

```
exm_list = [(4,8),(1,2),(4,5),(6,7),(10,20),(3,5),(3,2)]
for a,b in exm_list:
    if a and b % 2 == 0:
        print(f'{a,b} are the even numbers')
    else:
        print(f'one of {a,b} is the odd number')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry0iU.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Comment: Please don't use images of (or links to) code. Paste the code into the question, then immediately select it and either type Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button in the editor interface to format it properly.

Comment: what error you receive, for me is working fine

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not asking anything for the condition for 'a'. What you should state is the following:

```
exm_list = [(4,8),(1,2),(4,5),(6,7),(10,20),(3,5),(3,2)]
for a,b in exm_list:
    if a % 2 == 0 and b % 2 == 0:
        print(f'{a,b} are the even numbers')
    else:
        print(f'one of {a,b} is the odd number')
```

Let me know.

Comment: Thanks, @renauV,  in the original code the 'and' statement was getting applied to only 'b' and hence the 'a' is always true.

Comment: I do not believe so. Look at your example (1,2) and (6, 7). By running the program I posted, you will get for both "one is the odd number".  Maybe your problem should be restated. What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @PythonLearner in your case "if a" is equivalent to if a == 0 since a is an integer, when you write a condition ( if expr), python will try to evaluate the expr as a boolean. For an integer it will be "equals to 0", for a list it will be "list is empty" and so on...

Answer (score 0):

In you case

```
if a and b % 2 == 0:
```

is equivalent to

```
if bool(a) and bool(b % 2 == 0):
```

a is an integer so bool(a) is True if a is not 0